# writing form action path programmatically

Tags: 7, theming

Here is a custom user login form by Overriding the template. But can't understand how to print the destination/action path on the form. here is my code:

> **block--user--login.tpl.php**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="user-login-form" method="post" action="/node?destination=node">
  <div class="custom-form">
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
  <label for="edit-name">Username <span title="This field is required." class="form-    required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-text required" maxlength="60" size="15" value=""     name="name" id="edit-name">
</div>

    <div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass">
  <label for="edit-pass">Password <span title="This field is required." class="form-required">*</span></label>
  <input type="password" class="form-text required" maxlength="60" size="15" name="pass" id="edit-pass">
</div>

<div id="edit-actions" class="form-actions form-wrapper">
  <input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Log in" name="op" id="edit-submit">
</div>

<div class="item-list">
  <ul>
    <li class="first"><a title="Create a new user account." href="/user/register">Create new account</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a title="Request new password via e-mail."     href="/user/password">Request new password</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php print $elements['form_build_id']['#value']; ?> "     name="form_build_id">
    <input type="hidden" value="user_login_block" name="form_id">
  </div>
</form>
```

Here we are using a default path like `action="/node?destination=node"` its really a bad idea..
So i want to print the action path programmatically.. Any idea?
This maybe an idea: `<?php print $elements['actions']['#the_path']; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action is stored in the form's [`#action`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#action) property, so assuming your form is represented by the `$elements` variable in the template, something like this should do it:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="user-login-form" method="post" action="<?php echo $elements['#action']; ?>">
```